# Mouse middle click works only once

Tags: mouse

Just recently I'm having problems with middle click. After a reboot, it works the first time I use it, but then it doesn't work after that.

As far as I've investigated, that's the same on Linux and Windows. The mouse is Reaper ZMS-1000.

To me it sounds like a hardware issue, but it's strange that it works after a reboot every time just for one time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a case that there is a slight short in the mouse that controls the middle click function that could be "sticking" the button in the down/active state, the loss of power may cause the button to return to an inactive/available state. Check to see if unplugging the mouse from the USB and reconnecting it allows the middle click to work again.

If that turns out to be it, then you might be able to clean the contacts inside the mouse if you feel comfortable taking it apart.

Comment: I can clearly hear the click when clicking down and up, so it's not a mechanical issue, but it could be electrical. 

I think you are right about it being electrical of some sort. Plugging into a different USB port didn't work, but after opening it and closing it again (without any changes), now it seems to be working ok. Loose wire perhaps could explain it.

Thanks